# Meteor/jQuery/JS Change color of image with color picker

Tags: meteor

I am running Meteor and basically I have an image (an avatar) that has a face on it, and I want people to be able to customize the background color with a color picker. After they choose it the image (with the custom background) is saved in my public folder and I get the file path.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: you didnt try anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be:
 * Check how to display a color picker
 * Check how to manipulate a image
 * Check how to save a file on the server

Your question is to general, and providing a meaningfull answer would be like doing the work for you. But I would split it into above 3 steps which I guess can be easily googled for plenty of existing answers. Maybe not for Meteor, but for node.js or vanilla js.